# How to fetch mongodb documents created less than 8 hours?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Why I am not getting any results from MongoDB, I want to fetch documents which is created less than 8 hours not more than that.

```
let fetchAllDetails = async (findExpression) => {
    try {
        let data = await userDetails.find(findExpression)
        return data
    }
    catch (err) {
        logger.error(`DB Fetch All Error ---> ${JSON.stringify(err)}`)
        return false
    }
}

exports.remindUsers = async () => {
    let currentTime = Date.now()
    console.log(new Date(getCurrentTime() - 30000), new Date(getCurrentTime()))
    let fetchedUserData = await fetchAllDetails({ date_time: { $gt: new Date(currentTime - 6000) } }) // For one minute
    console.log(fetchedUserData)
}
```

**MongoDB Schema**

```
const userDetails = new mongoose.Schema({
    mobileNumber: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
    },
    date_time: {
        type: Date,
        required: true,
        default: Date.now()
    },
});
```

Comment: The filter should be set to `$gt: new Date(currentTime - (8 * 60 * 60 * 1000))`.

Comment: Or use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/): `{$gt: moment().subtract(8, 'hour').toDate()}` ([luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/index.html) and [dayjs](https://day.js.org/en/) provide almost the same syntax)